# I have this function and i am not sure what should i assosciate with the return statement to get what is required

Tags: python, function

```
    import csv
    f = open('C:\\Users\\keshabg\\Desktop\\sql_testing\\table_1.csv')
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)

    def try1(data,process,shift,lc):
        lev1=[]
        lev2=[]
        lev3=[]
        lev4=[]
        lev5=[]
        for row in csv_f:
            if data=='units':
                if row[3]=='KILO':
                    process='KILO'
                    if row[2]=='A':
                        shift='A'
                        if row[4]=='Level 1':
                            lc=='Level 1'
                            lev1.append(row[5])
                        if row[4]=='Level 2':
                            lc=='Level 2'
                            lev2.append(row[5])
                        if row[4]=='Level 3':
                            lc=='Level 3'
                            lev3.append(row[5])
                        if row[4]=='Level 4':
                            lc=='Level 4'
                            lev4.append(row[5])
                        if row[4]=='Level 5':
                            lc=='Level 5'
                            lev5.append(row[5])
            if data=='hours':
                if row[3]=='KILO':
                    process='KILO'
                    if row[2]=='A':
                        shift='A'
                        if row[4]=='Level 1':
                            lc=='Level 1'
                            lev1.append(row[6])
                        if row[4]=='Level 2':
                            lc=='Level 2'
                            lev2.append(row[6])
                        if row[4]=='Level 3':
                            lc=='Level 3'
                            lev3.append(row[6])
                        if row[4]=='Level 4':
                            lc=='Level 4'
                            lev4.append(row[6])
                       if row[4]=='Level 5':
                            lc=='Level 5'
                            lev5.append(row[6])
        return lev1,lev2,lev3,lev4,lev5
    a = try1("units","KILO","A","Level 1")
    print(a)
```

Whenever this function runs and whenever the user put in those four arguments to get the output i want it to return units on that shift of that process and that particular level but right now even when i put in Level 1, its giving me everything from level 1 to level . i am pretty sure thats because of the return statement which is returning everything. So to get the output i want how would i go about changing that? Any help will be greatly appreciated[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you lookup some python tutorials and start from there. There are many errors in your code and i suspect a few basic tutorials will help a lot.

Edit:
Learn more about python and how it works. For example you are using the compare sign `==` in a line and do nothing with the output. For example line `lc=='Level 1'`. I think you are trying to do multiple if statements? You can do that with `if cond1 and cond2:`.

You have hardcoded alot of keywords when you want to pass them along the function. And you are overwriting these keywords each row. See `process='KILO'` whenever the `row[3] == 'KILO'`.

So try to do more tutorials and examples to get better in coding.

My answer:

```py
 import csv
    f = open('C:\\Users\\keshabg\\Desktop\\sql_testing\\table_1.csv')
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)

    def try1(data,process,shift,lc):
        result = []
        if data == 'units':
            result_column = 5
        elif data == 'hours':
            result_column = 6
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError
        for row in csv_f:
            if row[2] == shift and row[3] == process and row[4] == lc:
                result.append(row[result_column])
        return result
    a = try1("units","KILO","A","Level 1")
    print(a)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate

Comment: Hey, thank you. i am new in python and i thought i learned all the basics but apparently and unfortunately that doesnt seem the case. Thank you, and i did learned a new way now.

Answer (score 0):

as said by Encrypted you should maybe learn a bit more about python,

for example

```
lc=='Level 1'
```

it is a comparison  and you don't do anything with it. maybe it should be in your if ?

check there https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html to know more about Comparisons

something else :
At the end you'r trying to put 5 results in one